# Aggregate geolocation data [long / lat]

Tags: r, geolocation, geospatial, latitude-longitude

I have a big dataset with a lot of geolocation data (long / lat), which I want to map dependent on the frequency. I just want to show the frequencies of the cities and areas, not of each exact location. Since the geo data might vary a little bit for each city, the data has to be aggregated / clustered.

Unfortunately, just rounding the number does not work. I have already tried to create a matrix to measure the distance of each point, but my vector memory is not sufficient. Is there a simpler way?

This is how the original data looks like:

```
$long     $lat     

12.40495  52.52001 
13.40233  52.50141 
13.37698  52.51607
13.38886  52.51704
13.42927  52.48457
9.993682  53.55108
9.992470  53.55334
10.000654 53.55034
11.58198  48.13513
11.51450  48.13910
...       ...
```

The result should look like this:

```
$long     $lat     $count

13.40495  52.52001 5
9.993682  53.55108 3
11.58198  48.13513 2
...       ...      ...
```

**EDIT 1:**
To cluster the points to one single point, a range of 25-50 km is fine.

**EDIT 2:**
This is how the map looks like, if I don't aggregate the points. I want to prevent the overlapping of the circles. [image]

Comment: I guess you need `library(dplyr); df1 %>% group_by(city) %>% summarise(long = first(long), lat = first(lat), count = n())`

Comment: The example was bad. The city names for an area do not have to be the same. I have edited the question and removed the city column, since they do not matter.

Comment: I think you'd first need to decide what range is acceptable for you.  You could then create a new column and summarize off of that.  Post your data in a reproducible format with `dput(head(yourdata))` would help us help you.

Comment: Well, I think an acceptable range would be 25-50 km. The data only consists of the lat & long coordinate columns (the earlier mentioned city column is too specific. I don't want to show each village in a small radius).